# @ElementCollection vs @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING), and how to decide it my enum is an entity

Tags: java, jpa, database-design, enums

I'm confused about when to use one over the other, or both together.

From the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969059/difference-between-onetomany-and-elementcollection) question, I get that `@ElementCollection` is used when we want to map a non-entity. But then there seems to be cases when both are used at the same time, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227747/jpa-elementcollection-enumerated-not-inserting),

```
  @ElementCollection(targetClass=Role.class)
  @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
  public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
  }
```

or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998824/mapping-setenum-using-elementcollection),

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Days.class)
@CollectionTable(name = "days", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "rule_id"))
@Column(name = "daysOfWeek", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Set<Days> getDays() {
    return days;
}
```

But then, I don't really understand when they shouldn't go together. I guess, but I'm not sure, that the question is whether my enum is an entity or not, as said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3153172/3748908) answer.

> You should decide whether your Platform is an entity or not.

So my questions are:

1. Do `@ElementCollection` and `@Enumerated` overlap in any way or are completely independent? If independent, I decide if my entity is mapped, and then if it happens to be an enum. Correct?
2. How do I decide if I want my enum to be an entity? An example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: CollectionTable is for non-Entity elements.. The first one (JoinTable) is inappropriate for non-entities. An Enum is not an Entity, ever!

Comment: @NeilStockton: So `ElementCollection` and `JoinTable` shouldn't ever appear together? Why doesn't hibernate complain about it?

Comment: maybe because it ignores JoinTable? who knows. Ask a Hibernate developer. The JPA spec is very clear